# Turning numbers to hex values, but make them double digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, hex

**Problem:** I am building a drawing board app that uses a number to hex converter function. Right now they only return single digits for certain conversions.

**EXAMPLE**: `r:0,g:0, b:0` returns `#000`, and not `#000000`. I believe this is why I can't get my colors to update properly, and only values will work.

**Desired Result:** I want my numbers to be converted to double digits. So `R:0,G:0,B:`) would convert to `#000000` and not `#000`, although they're the same thing, other colors rely on double digits, from my understanding. Basically I want all my number to hex conversions to be 6 digits.

**[SOLVED]**: Changed the way of getting my values to css's `rgb(r,g,b)` instead of using hex values.

**JSBIN** http://jsbin.com/doqiwocufa/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Javascript:

```
var $red = 0;

function changeRedNumboxValue(value) {
    var $numBox = $('#redNumber');
    $red = value;
    $numBox.val($red);
  
    console.log($red);
}

function changeRedSliderVal(value) {
    var $slider = $('#red');
    $red = value;
    $slider.val($red);
  
    console.log($red);
}

var $green = 0;

function changeGreenNumboxValue(value) {
    var $numBox = $('#greenNumber');
    $green = value;
    $numBox.val($green);
  
    console.log($green);
}

function changeGreenSliderVal(value) {
    var $slider = $('#green');
    $green = value;
    $slider.val($green);
  
    console.log($green);
}

var $blue = 0;

function changeBlueNumboxValue(value) {
    var $numBox = $('#blueNumber');
    $blue = value;
    $numBox.val($blue);
  
    console.log($blue);

}

function changeBlueSliderVal(value) {
    var $slider = $('#blue');
    $blue = value;
    $slider.val($blue);
  
    console.log($blue);
}

//CONVERT RGB TO HEX
function rgbToHex() {
    $hexRed = $red.toString(16);
    $hexGreen = $green.toString(16);
    $hexBlue = $blue.toString(16);
  
    console.log($hexRed);
    console.log($hexGreen);
    console.log($hexBlue);
  
    return '#' + $hexRed + $hexGreen + $hexBlue;
}

//UPDATE COLOR BASED ON HEX VALUES
function updateColor() {
    $colorChosen = $('#color-chosen');
    $color = rgbToHex();
    $colorChosen.css('background-color', $color);
}

updateColor();
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <span>Blue</span>
      <input id="red" type="range" name="amount2" value="0" min="0" max="255" oninput="changeNumboxValue(this.value)">
      <input id="redNumber" type="number" name="amountInput2" value="0" min="0" max="255" oninput="changeSliderVal(this.value)">
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#color-chosen {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need some padding with `0` and cut the string with [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

> The **slice()** method extracts a section of a string and returns a new string.

```
 $hexRed = ('0' +  $red.toString(16)).slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `#ABC` will be interpreted as `#AABBCC`. If you use only 3 numbers in hexa, the color code for it will be twice the first letter, twice the second and twice the third. This means that `#000` is the same with `#000000`.
For other colors, you might need `r:AB`, etc. In this case, `g`, `b` need to be in two letters.

I think that this is your problem. Sometimes you get 1 letter for a color and 2 for other colors resulting into a 5 hexa numbers conversion.